# Ruby on Rails - Submitting a nested resource form does not save, produces "Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**EDIT Two:** Server log:

```
Started POST "/users" for IPADDRESS at 2019-01-15 11:02:29 +1100
Processing by Users::UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TOKEN", "search_address"=>{"search_address"=>"1 Dr Carlton B Goodlett Pl, San Francisco, CA 94102, USA"}, "commit"=>"Save Search Address"}
  User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 24]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

**EDIT**: Quick note, but in the users controllers, they do not have a before_action call. And I want only logged_in users to access the search page, and the update method.

**Obtaining a Filter chain halted on a nested resource form. What should I add in the code below to ensure the form submitted is saved in teh corresponding table?**

I have a User and Search Address model, the purpose is a User can input a address that is saved in the Search Address table. My issue is once a user submits a form, I get an authentication error.

I've read on stack about adding something such as:

```
prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [:cancel ]
```

But, I'm unsure where to put it and, even then, where would I place it within my code? I've put the code before in my User controller, and obtained subsequent errors. Hence, why I'm interested to know if there is another way to solve my issue or, if not, what should I do correctly in utilising the above code.

I've removed some code so it's easier to understand.

View:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @user do |f| %>

    <%= fields_for :search_address, @user.build_search_address do |g| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= g.label :search_address, 'Search Address' %>
        <br/>
        <%= g.text_field :search_address, :class => "form-control" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit 'Save Search Address' %>
  <% end %>
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "search_addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.string   "search_address"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "search_addresses", ["user_id"], name: "index_search_addresses_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "username"
  end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :search_address, dependent: :destroy, :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :search_address
  geocoded_by :address, :latitude => :latitude, :longitude => :longitude
  after_validation :geocode
end
```

Search Address model:

```
class SearchAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  geocoded_by :search_address, :latitude => :latitude, :longitude => :longitude
end
```

User controller:

```
  def search_page
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_search_address
  end

  def update
    @users = User.find(params[:id])
    @users.update_attributes!(user_params)
        redirect_to :back
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user)
    params[:user].permit(:email, search_addresses_attributes: [:search_address])
  end

end
```

Comment: Which `before_action` calls do you have in UsersController? Who should have access to `search_page` and `update` actions - only logged_in users?

Comment: Hi Vasillisa, apologies for the late reply.

In my user controllers, there are no before_action calls. And, for accessing of search_page and update, it should only be logged_in users.

Comment: If you want to restrict access with logged in users only you should add `before_action :authenticate_user!` to the UsersController. But it unlikely will solve the problem. Please, add full server log of the failed action with error stacktrace

Comment: Hi Vasilisa, I've just added the server log of the failed action now. Regarding the error stack trace, I can't seem to find it sorry. However, if it is essential, I'll tr and find it.

Comment: You using Devise?

Comment: Hi Dimitrius, yes I am using devise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out. Let's look at your controller actions and server logs. You submit the form in search_address action and you want go to update action. But you define @user in search_address action as User.new and that's why you go to the create action (`Processing by Users::UsersController#create as HTML` in server logs). Your user is logged in, but create action requires no logged in users (normally it fires on sign up), that's why you get `Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected`.

If I understood correctly, you want to update search_address for current user. It should be:

```
# Users::UsersController
def search_page
end

def update
  current_user.update_attributes!(user_params)
  # it's always a good idea to specify what to do, if accidentally there is no "back"
  redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, search_address_attributes: [:search_address])
end

# search_address.html.erb
<%= semantic_form_for current_user do |f| %>
  <% f.object.search_address ||= f.object.build_search_address %>
  <%= fields_for :search_address do |addr| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= addr.label :search_address, 'Search Address' %>
      <br/>
      <%= addr.text_field :search_address, :class => "form-control" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit 'Save Search Address' %>
<% end %>
```

I see some problems with nested params in the server log (it is `"search_address"=>{}`, should be `"search_address_attributes"=>{}`), but it should be fixed after form update.

Comment: Hi Vasilisa! Thank you so much for your extensive help and guidance, the form is now working perfectly and I now have a better understanding of why it's working and how I can implement this same thing in the future, if need be.

Comment: @JamesWu, happy to help you! :)